# HTTP Promise isn't Rejected When MockConnection Returns 400 http Status

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

My model class is:

```
export class RuntimeSettings {
    A: number,
    B: boolean,
    C: string
}
```

And I have a service class, which grabs and pushes the data object through web API:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { AppSettings } from './appSettings';
import { RuntimeSettings } from './runtimesettings';

@Injectable()
export class RuntimeSettingsService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getRuntimeSettings(): Promise<RuntimeSettings> {
        return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT)
            .toPromise()
            .then(function (response) { 
                let temp: RuntimeSettings = response.json().Z.R;
                return temp;
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    updateRuntimeSettings(settings: RuntimeSettings): Promise<any> {
        // assemble the data
        let data: any = {
            R: settings
        };
        // send the PUT request
        return this.http
            .put(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT, JSON.stringify(data))
            .toPromise()
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);  
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

And my unit test file for this service class is:

```
import {
    async, inject, TestBed
} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {
    MockBackend,
    MockConnection
} from '@angular/http/testing';

import {
    HttpModule, Http, XHRBackend, Response, ResponseOptions
} from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { RuntimeSettings } from './runtimesettings';
import { RuntimeSettingsService } from './runtimesettings.service';
import { AppSettings } from './appSettings';

class mm {
    RuntimeSettings: RuntimeSettings;
}

class ff {
    X: number;
    Y: string;
    Z: mm;
}

function makeResponseData(): ff {
    return {
        X: 72,
        Y: "JYL418",
        Z: {
            R: {
                A: 6080,
                B: true,
                C: "Mark XII"
            }
        }
    }
}

function makeRuntimeSettings(): RuntimeSettings {
    return {
        A: 6080,
        B: true,
        C: "Mark XII"
    }
}

describe('RuntimeSettingsService (mockBackend)', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpModule],
            providers: [
                RuntimeSettingsService,
                { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend }
            ]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    describe('when getRuntimeSettings', () => {
        let backend: MockBackend;
        let service: RuntimeSettingsService;
        let response: Response;

        beforeEach(inject([Http, XHRBackend], (http: Http, be: MockBackend) => {
            backend = be;
            service = new RuntimeSettingsService(http);
            let options = new ResponseOptions({ status: 200, body: makeResponseData() });
            response = new Response(options);
        }));

        it('should have expected fake settings of C, B and A', async(inject([], () => {
            backend.connections.subscribe((c: MockConnection) => c.mockRespond(response));
            service.getRuntimeSettings()
                .then(settings => {
                    expect(
                        settings.C == "Mark XII"
                        && settings.B == true
                        && settings.A == 6080
                    ).toBeTruthy('should have expected values');
                });
        })));

        it('should treat 500 as an exception', async(inject([], () => {
            let resp = new Response(new ResponseOptions({ status: 500 }));
            backend.connections.subscribe((c: MockConnection) => c.mockRespond(resp));
            service.getRuntimeSettings()
                .then(s => {    // failure is the expected test result
                    fail('should never reach here');
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    //console.log('Vince: ' + err);
                    expect(err).toContain('Cannot read property '); // TODO: seems to be useless ? err should be an object of the response
                });

        })));
    });


    describe('when updateRuntimeSettings', () => {
        let backend: MockBackend;
        let service: RuntimeSettingsService;
        let response: Response;

        beforeEach(inject([Http, XHRBackend], (http: Http, be: MockBackend) => {
            backend = be;
            service = new RuntimeSettingsService(http);
            let options = new ResponseOptions({ status: 204 });
            response = new Response(options);
        }));

        it('should have expected data in the request', async(inject([], () => {
            backend.connections.subscribe(
                (c: MockConnection) => {
                    let body = c.request.json();
                    expect(
                        body.R.A == 6068
                        && body.B == true
                        && body.C == "Mark XII"
                    ).toBeTruthy('the data pushed through the PUT api should be....');
                    //console.log(body);
                    c.mockRespond(response);
                }
            );
            service.updateRuntimeSettings(makeRuntimeSettings());
        })));

        it('should treat 400 as an exception', async(inject([], () => {
            let resp = new Response(
                new ResponseOptions({ status: 400, body: '{"Message": "The request is invalid."}' })
            );

            backend.connections.subscribe(
                (c: MockConnection) => c.mockRespond(resp)
            );

            service.updateRuntimeSettings(makeRuntimeSettings())
                .then(s => {
                    //console.log('V: ' + s.json().Message);
                    //fail('should never reach here');
                    // TODO: failure is the expected test result, the execution should not get here, but it does reach here
                    expect(400 == s.status
                        && 'The request is invalid.' == s.json().Message)
                        .toBeTruthy('the status code should be 400');
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('Vince: ' + err);
                    expect(err.json().Message).toContain('The request is invalid.'); // TODO: seems to be useless ?
                    // TODO: the execution should get here, but it does not get here
                });

        })));

    });

});
```

My question is, in the second test case of getRuntimeSettings(), returning status of 500 will result in the promise being rejected, since its execution goes to catch() instead of the callback passed to then(). This behaviour is the same as the case of real ajax calls.

But in the second test of updateRuntimeSettings(), the mock back-end returns 400 http status to the PUT request, and the promise object is resolved, as the execution goes into the callback passed to then(). And that is different from the real ajax call. Say, if I call it with my real server-side API, and the API returns a response with 400, it will be rejected.

Does it have anything to do with HTTP method? Do I need to specify PUT when using MockConnection? Or is that just a bug of MockConnection.